# What is the release date of "Ghost in the Shell: Arise" in US?

Tags: ghost-in-the-shell-arise

According to various nets and [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_in_the_Shell:_Arise), *Ghost in the Shell: Arise* "is scheduled for limited cinematic release in Japan on June 22, 2013."

What I'd like to know is, when its release in the United States will be?

---

Border 1--the first of four episodes in the *ARISE* series--is available at Mitsuwa Japanese Grocery in Santa Monica. It's $9.99. Border 2 will be coming out November 30, 2013 in Japan, but I'm not sure how it will be finding itself into the United States' market after this date.

Comment: In case you want to import it... the *Arise* Bluray [will have](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2013-05-01/ghost-in-the-shell-arise-blu-ray-to-have-english-subs) English subtitles.

Comment: `Where can you get Logicoma action figures in the United States?` Please ask that as a seperate question ;)

Answer (score 5):

Ghost in the Shell: Arise is not yet licensed. That means there's no release planned in the US yet.

**UPDATE**

[Ghost in the Shell: Arise is now licensed by Funimation](http://funimation.tumblr.com/post/52976810089/flower-mound-tx-june-14-2013-funimation). In October 2014, the first two parts have been released on BD and DVD, while parts 3 and 4 have been released a year later. (At least) the first three parts are also available at Netflix.

Comment: I see, so I just asked the university library to purchase this item for their East Asian Library collection. Do you think the purchasing representative for the library will find a way to get it? Given that, according to Krazer, "the Arise Bluray will have English subtitles."

Comment: I don't know how easy it is in your country, as I'm from Germany. But when the BDs will have subs, it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: What are "BDs"?

Comment: If you were to buy the film that has subtitles where would you buy it?

Comment: I know BDs as Bluray Discs :D. I would ask amazon or the local bookstore.